# Apply Logcat filter ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$ in Console

Tags: android, eclipse, bash, filter, logcat

I'm using Logcat with the nice full-color debugging script by Jeff Sharkey. But unfortunately it's messed up by the known bug of the latest sdk tools: 
Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 The filter ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$ works in Eclipse, but i don't how to use it in the bash.
Cheers Markus

Comment: Are you saying you are using the full-color debugging script inside eclipse? if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just pipe the output from the script and grep out the problematic log statements. i don't know the script of which you speak, but here's what i do from the command line.

```
adb logcat | grep -v nativeGetEnabledTags
```

it appears this does not work for JS's script since it does some trickery with stdout to determine the terminal width. if stdout is grep, then this won't work. you can get around this by commenting out line 28,29 and 135, but you lose the nice line wrapping.